# Best way to pass parameters to MDX query

Tags: mdx

Best way to pass parameters to MDX query ? I am trying to figure out the multiple ways that could be used to handle different params.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**StrToMember**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146022.aspx) or [**StrToValue**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144951.aspx).